# How can I listen to communication between a process and a serial port?

Tags: serial-port

On a Gentoo Linux machine, a process is communicating with another computer via serial port (`/dev/ttyS1`). I want to listen to this communication (i.e. what is being sent/received by the process) without further interfering.

How can I achieve this with just basic Linux tools? I even can change the serial port the process is communicating with, so maybe I can 'shortcut' two devices (`/dev/ttyS1` and `/dev/xxx`) listen to all communication, when all output to `/dev/ttyS1` is forwarded to `/dev/xxx` and vice versa. But how do I do it? Something with `socat`?

Comment: ethtool ? yes I know it will not work but you never know

Comment: I am looking for basic linux tools, nothing exotic.

Comment: Nothing exotic about [ethtool](http://packages.gentoo.org/package/sys-apps/ethtool).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach (not necessarily the best...) would be to attach `strace` to the process (or, in order to handle the race condition, to a wrapper script which `exec`s to this process), set `strace` to maximum string length and then catch all `read()`s and `write()`s (or whatever your process uses). After that you grep the lines with the right file descriptor (which should always be the same; if not then you have to catch the `open()`s, too).

Comment: Nice idea, but what are the file descriptors for `/dev/ttyS1`?

Comment: @Alex That depends on what the process is doing. You can see them in `/proc/$PID/fd` and in `strace` as the return value of the `open()` calls.

Comment: See also the `-e read=x -e write=y` options to get a hex dump of what is read/written on fd x.

Answer (score 11):

[interceptty](http://www.suspectclass.com/sgifford/interceptty/interceptty.html) looks like what you want.

I found that from this [Ubuntu page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualSerialPort)

interceptty - Intercept traffic to and from a serial port.

Example

> If you want to use interceptty as an external serial monitor
>   [connected to two serial ports on your machine and relaying between
>   them, while recording the output]
>
> you can use one device as the backend, and use the -p option to tell
>   the frontend not to create it's own tty, but just use the one you tell
>   it:

```
interceptty -s 'ispeed 19200 ospeed 19200' /dev/ttyS0 -p /dev/ttyS1 -
```

**Output**

> interceptty prints its output in a fairly unattractive, painful to
>   look at format. However, it is very easy for other programs to parse.
>   For an example of how to post-process this output into something
>   appropriate to whatever you are intercepting, see the included Perl
>   script interceptty-nicedump.
>
> Output lines are in this general format:
>
> < 0x54 (T)
>
> > ```
> >   0x4b (K)  ^ Direction    ^^^^ Hex code (to real device)
> >     ^^^ ASCII character (to real device)
> >      ^^^^ Hex code (from real device)
> >           ^^^ ASCII character (from real device) The direction marker is a '<' if this character was sent to the backend device, and
> > ```
> >
> > '>' if it was received from the backend device. It is always followed
> >     by a single space. If the character was received from the real device,
> >     a tab will appear next (this makes the output easier to follow). After
> >     that is the hex code for the character, and the ASCII representation
> >     of the character if it is an ASCII character.

Comment: it look nice though if ethtool is exotic I can't even think about a tool nobody ever heard of :D