# VT100 terminal emulation to use with a Java-based 8-bit computer emulator

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen, serial-port, programming, serial-console

I'm successfully using GNU Screen as serial terminal to "talk" to my Altair 8800 clone (http://altairclone.com/) using serial line. The command I use is:

```
screen -istrip /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Screen does the VT100 emulation, strips off MSB from output etc. - works perfect.

Now, I'm writing an emulator of the Altair 8800 in Java and would like to use some terminal emulator to connect and talk to it, just like it was a real machine through a serial device.

What is the best way to solve this in the Linux world? Is there a way to use `screen` for that? Something tells me the solution is trivial, but I just don't know it yet.

Comment: I'm not sure, this seems on topic. He's asking for a recommendation of how to connect using a VT100 emulator to an Altair 8800. This seems like it could go on SO and SU as well.

Comment: @slm The question is about how to make the Java program present a terminal interface. That's Java programming. We don't cater to programming questions here. user72879: your question is going to be migrated to [so] soon (do not repost).

Comment: @Gilles - not gonna disagree, but it seemed borderline since it sounds like he's asking how to connect to the serial terminal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/117037/31760

Answer (score 0):

`screen` supports `telnet` protocol (like so: `screen //telnet destination`), so you could implement that in your emulator.