# How to read/write data to my ttyS0 port on my HMI running on Linux?

Tags: linux, monitoring, serial-port

I've purchased a HMI running on a stripped down Linux (C compiler missing). I connected the HMI to my network and I'm able to acces it by powershell. What I'm trying to achieve is to write data to this RS232 port(i think ttys0) and monitor the incoming data in my powershell. I'm a noob with Linux tho, hope someone can help!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send data to a serial port and see any answer?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117037/how-to-send-data-to-a-serial-port-and-see-any-answer)

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/556315/5132 .