# Working with file descriptors in the (bash) shell?

Tags: bash, shell, files, exec, stty

I came across the following set of shell commands for reading and writing to serial ports, from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/332999/428932) thread:

```
stty -speed 19200 < /dev/ttyS0 # sets the speed of the port
exec 99<>/dev/ttyS0 (or /dev/ttyUSB0...etc)
printf "AT\r" >&99
read answer <&99  # this reads just a CR
read answer <&99  # this reads the answer OK
exec 99>&-
```

I am having trouble understanding the lines that use file descriptors, particularly these two lines:

```
exec 99<>/dev/ttyS0 (or /dev/ttyUSB0...etc)
```

and

```
exec 99>&-
```

What are they doing? Is there any reason why `99` is being used as opposed to any other number? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There is no special meaning of `99`; that was just "a file descriptor that we are pretty sure won't be in use".

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment this is just identification of this file handler. Just like `STDIN` have ID 0, `STDOUT` have ID 1, `STDERR` have ID 2.

For example:

```
echo aa >/dev/null
```

and

```
echo aa 1>/dev/null
```

are the same

Comment: Thanks. Is there any reason we are opening a file descriptor instead of directly redirecting into the file by its name?

Comment: @FirstUser, this will create more unified way to redirect different messages. Also you will have only one place to change the file name (in case of need)